# Parse JSON in NiFi Python script

Tags: python, jython, apache-nifi

I basically receiving a flow file and i have to get value of a key.

```
import json
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback


class FlowFileParser(StreamCallback):
def __init__(self):
    pass
def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    obj = json.loads(text)
    newObj = obj['priority']
    outputStream.write(bytearray(newObj.encode('utf-8')))



flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:
    #flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "priority", "5")
    priority = FlowFileParser()
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", priority)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

But i am getting an below exception " putAttribute(): 3rd arg can't be coerced to String in  at line number 23"

The input flowfile could be as

```
{
"name": "martin",
"priority":"5"
}
```

I just want the file name to be 5

Comment: the error is obvious: the 3d parameter for `session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", priority)` must be string. and it seems the variable priority is not a string at this moment. and if you just need to parse json and put some value from it into flowfile attribute - just use EvaluateJsonPath processor.

Comment: Hi Daggett i do not want to use any service, i want it to be in execute script. cos in future it will be easy to extend or add additional feature.

Comment: the code is wrong. `priority = FlowFileParser()` is just creation of a new class without running (processing) flow file. check the following examples: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75032/executescript-cookbook-part-1.html (there are part 2 and part 3 links in this article)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass an object into a string argument:

```
priority = FlowFileParser()
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", priority)
```

priority is an object reference to FlowFileParser(), and the third argument to putAttribute needs to be a string.

Comment: What should i change to access the priority element. i am new to python and nifi please guide me

Comment: I can't really help much with the python part, but you need to parse the json content somehow, you read it in here obj = json.loads(text)  and now somehow need to extract priority from obj

Comment: NiFi already has built in processors for this type of thing like EvaluateJsonPath where you just say priority = $.priority and it will extract it from the json content